# How to execute a local procedure using execute immedate?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below PL SQL Block:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON   

DECLARE
v_sql VARCHAR2(500);
f1 VARCHAR2(20) := 'abc';
p_procname VARCHAR2 (30) := 'OPENLOG';

   PROCEDURE OPENLOG (file_name IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      NULL;
   END;    

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Begin');
v_sql := 'BEGIN ' || p_procname || '(:a); END;';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING IN f1;
END;
/
```

When I execute the above block, I get the error:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'OPENLOG' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at line 19
```

However, if the procedure OPENLOG is part of a package, then it works fine.

Please advise how to execute a local procedure using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Is the entire source of the procedure(s) returned by your query, or are several procedures always defined in your anonymous block and the query just tells you which to execute? Either is a bit weird, but there might be a way, depending on exactly what's happening. A more complete example might be useful.

Comment: All the procedures are defined in the ananymous block. The query just tells which ones to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Amarillo said you can't execute a locally-defined procedure dynamically, as it doesn't exist in the SQL scope the dynamic section will be using.

The situation you describe is that all the procedures are defined in the anonymous block's `DECLARE` section and you are running a query that tells you which of them to execute - and presumably which also gives you the arguments to pass. You can just use an `if`/`else` construct or a `case` statement to execute the appropriate procedures, something like:

```
DECLARE
  ...
BEGIN
  FOR data IN (SELECT procname, arg1, arg2, ... from <your_query>) LOOP
    CASE data.procname
      WHEN 'OPENLOG' THEN
        openlog(data.arg1);
      WHEN 'WRITELOG' THEN
        writelog(data.arg1, data.arg2);
      WHEN ...
        ...
      ELSE
         -- handle/report an invalid procedure name
         -- or skip the `ELSE` and let CASE_NOT_FOUND be thrown
    END CASE;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You just need one `WHEN` condition and appropriate procedure call for each procedure. You can also either have an `ELSE` to catch any unexpected procedure names or let the `CASE_NOT_FOUND` exception (ORA-06592) be thrown, depending on what you need to happen if that ever occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
DECLARE
v_sql VARCHAR2(500);
f1 VARCHAR2(20) := 'abc';
p_procname VARCHAR2 (30) := 'OPENLOG';

   PROCEDURE OPENLOG (file_name IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      NULL;
   END;    

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Begin');
openlog(f1);
END;
```

You don't need to use execute immediate with begin end in this case, because you have the procedure in the declare section.

The other way is create the procedure as a database object like this:

```
       CREATE PROCEDURE OPENLOG (file_name IN VARCHAR2)
       IS
       BEGIN
          NULL;
       END;
```

And the you can use execute immediate:

```
DECLARE
v_sql VARCHAR2(500);
f1 VARCHAR2(20) := 'abc';
p_procname VARCHAR2 (30) := 'OPENLOG';

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Begin');
v_sql := 'BEGIN ' || p_procname || '(:a); END;';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING IN f1;
END;
```

Comment: I want it through execute immedate only becuase I have set of procedures which are returned as part of a query result and I want to execute all of them.

Comment: Due to some constraint, it cannot be created, I can only have it as local procedure meaning without "create".

Comment: Wow, in this case you should contact to your database administrator and ask for 'create procedure' privilege, because i think there is no way of execute procedures declared in anonymous blocks of a dynamic way